# How to connect Excel to a Web API (Azure AD + Bearer)

Tags: excel, rest, azure-active-directory, jwt, bearer-token

I'm trying to connect an Excel Worksheet to my API authorized in Microsoft Azure AD and protected by an Bearer Token.

[image]

But I don't know how to retrieve my bearer token on Excel, can someone explain it to me ( I'm new on Azure, I may had forgot some parameters in my config)

I can already access my API with Postman/Browser.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Bearer token and get it authorized and call the API:

Set up the service as below,

```html
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;
                },
                options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                });

The pipeline is defined as below:
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
           
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }

My AzureAd configs are the following:
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": https://login.microsoftonline.com/,
    "Domain": "XXX.com",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXX"
  }
```

The controllers are only protected with the [Authorize] attribute, It will not check for any kind of scopes.

With this set up, we will be able to call the API successfully